# Make android toast not cancellable

Tags: android, toast

I am showing a toast in my app. The problem is that in some devices (Samsung galaxy s6) the toast is cancelled when touching the screen. This problem doesn't happens in other devices (Nexus 5)

This is my code

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = li.inflate(R.layout.popup_tutorial_privado, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popup));
toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Take a step back

*Avoid using `Toast` altogether* if you need more control and use a `Dialog` that dismisses itself after `n` time. You could write a method as simple as this one, that would produce something functionally equivalent to a `Toast` but with the added freedom of controlling when and how it's dismissed.

```
public void customToast(String message, int duration){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_toast);
    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    //Customize the views, add actions, whatever
    ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText(message);
    dialog.show();
    //Auto cancel the dialog after `duration`
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    },duration);
}
```

#### Demo

[image]

#### Note

If you want the dialog to be shown for the exact amount of time a long toast lasts, use `3500` since `private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500;`

#### But wait! The dialog takes focus and I need to retain it!

Ok, ok, you may be writing inside an `EditText` and the `Dialog` acting like a `Toast` takes control of your focus and your keyboard hides and everything is lost. To prevent this, simply set an extra flag, that will tell the `Dialog` that it's not focusable, and that it should not attempt to request it.

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

Keep in mind that if you're showing the `Toast` by watching text changes in an `EditText` you should keep a flag of some sort, to know whether it's being shown, or is already shown, or whatever, otherwise you'll end up with multiple dialogs.

Comment: I have a problem. I need to keep writing in the keyboard while the customToast is visible. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A toast provides simple feedback about an operation in a small popup. It only fills the amount of space required for the message and the current activity remains visible and interactive.
the toast does not interact with user, it just like "comes and go" you can not set it cancelable true or false.
you should use [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to achieve what you want.

Comment: But how do you avoid the toast be cancelled in some devices?

Comment: what do you mean by some device?

Comment: In the Samsung galaxy s6. I show the toast and when I touch the screen the toast disappears.

Comment: you need to use alert dialogs.i think. see the update answer.

Comment: Use snack bar with infinite time in time parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the documentation:

> A toast provides simple feedback about an operation in a small popup. It only fills the amount of space required for the message and the current activity remains visible and interactive. For example, navigating away from an email before you send it triggers a "Draft saved" toast to let you know that you can continue editing later. Toasts automatically disappear after a timeout.

For the behavior your explain, you do use snackbar with infinite time
[Snackbar documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)